# Invalid points assigned to 2D edge collider Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following method that draws a `LineRenderer` and an `EdgeCollider2D`.

```
    protected override void Draw ( EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider2D, LineRenderer lineRenderer , float resolution , GoSpline[] spline , float startFill , float targetFill )
{

    float increment = ( 1f / resolution );
    List< Vector3 > vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    List< Vector2 > pts = new List<Vector2>();

    float t = 0;

    while ( targetFill > t )
    {
        vertices.Add( spline[ 0 ].getPointOnPath( t ) );
        pts.Add( new Vector2(spline[ 0 ].getPointOnPath( t ).x, spline[ 0 ].getPointOnPath( t ).y));
        Vector3 v3 = spline[ 0 ].getPointOnPath( t );
        Debug.Log (v3);

        t += increment;
    }

    lineRenderer.SetVertexCount( vertices.Count );
    lineRenderer.SetPositions( vertices.ToArray() );

    edgeCollider2D.points = pts.ToArray ();

}
```

I keep getting the error

```
Invalid points assigned to 2D edge collider.
UnityEngine.EdgeCollider2D:set_points(Vector2[])
```

at the line

```
edgeCollider2D.points = pts.ToArray ();
```

Also, occasionally when `lineRenderer.positionCount` is 0, `edgeCollider2D.points` has 2 points, which should not be the case, they should both have no points.

I tried replacing

```
edgeCollider2D.points = pts.ToArray ();
```

with

```
edgeCollider2D.points = vertices.Cast<Vector2> ().ToArray();
```

but this gave the following error in addition:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateCastIterator>c__Iterator0`1[UnityEngine.Vector2].MoveNext ()
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm guessing the first error (`Invalid points assigned to 2D edge collider`) is due to having tried to supply zero points. There may be an internal check that says that the number of points must be greater than or equal to 2.  Attempting to set 0 points in the editor throws a warning on the component, but does allow the modification. The "2 points" you were seeing may be ghost data.

Comment: @Draco18s I've not put any check to ensure points are greater or equal to 2. I also don't think they are ghost data because when i select the game object the edge colliders are visible. I believe there should be a way I can workaround it, with a condition of some sort (which I've not figured out) that would ensure consistency with the line renderer `positionCount` and edge collider `points`.

Comment: Before assigning `pts.ToArray` to `edgeCollider2D.points`, make sure that the length of data in  `pts.ToArray` is >=2. Add that check with an `if` statement and see if that helps

Comment: @Programmer that gets rid of the `Invalid points assigned to 2D edge collider` error, but because of the condition it leaves 2 edge points when the line renderer position count is 0. I am using my method to draw and erase lines, that's why I need both line renderer position count and edge points to be consistently 0 in the end (generally having the same values)

Comment: If `LineRenderer` position count is 0 then it's no line. Instead of assigning that to the  `edgeCollider2D.points`, disable the `EdgeCollider2D` component. When the position count >= 2, enable the `EdgeCollider2D`  and then assign `edgeCollider2D.points`.

Comment: @Programmer that solves it, thanks a lot. That didn't occur to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before assigning the array `pts.ToArray()` to `edgeCollider2D.points`, make sure that the array is not `null`.

Also make sure that the length of the data/array you want to assign (`pts.ToArray`) to the `EdgeCollider2D` points is `>=` *2*. You will get that error if it is not.

Both of these can be checked with a simple `if` statement. If the array to assign to the `edgeCollider2D.points` is `0` or `<` *2*, simply disable the `EdgeCollider2D` component or handle it which ever way you want but **don't** assign that array to the `EdgeCollider2D` points as you will get that exception.

```
List<Vector2> pts = new List<Vector2>();

//The array to assign to the EdgeCollider2D points 
Vector2 []tempArray = pts.ToArray();

//Check if point is valid
if(tempArray != null && tempArray.Length >= 2){
    //Enable EdgeCollider2D if previously disabled
    if(!edgeCollider2D.enabled)
    edgeCollider2D.enabled = true;

    //Ok to assign the array
    edgeCollider2D.points = tempArray;
}
else
{
    //Point is NOT valid, disable the `EdgeCollider2D` component.
    Debug.Log("Point cannot be null nor less than 2");
    edgeCollider2D.enabled = false;
}
```